# Remove trailing zeros from currency string android

Tags: android, currency, numberformatter

I tried to convert int to curency format and everything worked as I expected

example 1000 --> Rp1.000

but on certain devices the results are not what I expected
i.e. 1000 --> **Rp1.000,00**

So the question is how to remove the last 2 extra nolls if the device displays them.

my current code:

```
    public static String toUang(String DigitUang) {

        return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("in", "ID")).format(Double.parseDouble(DigitUang));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution here would probably be to fix your locale settings and handle the presentation there.  That being said, you also could probably handle this using a regex replacement:

```java
public static String toUang(String DigitUang) {

    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("in", "ID"))
                       .format(Double.parseDouble(DigitUang))
                       .replaceAll("[,.]00$", "");
}
```

Comment: some device doesnt have locale format setting, but this work as well, thanks